Magento 2 Issue related to same Shipment Email Sent Multiple Times to Consumers
We have faced issues in the automated emails in our application. Some of our Shipment automated emails were triggered multiple times to the same recipients.

Same day we have a large number of error logs for a ‘Order back in stock' email.
I have checked the logs there are no errors. Should I check the email service SMTP logs also or anything else?
